# Barplot large data set

Tags: matlab, plot, bigdata

I have a matrix data of student scores(600x10), where 600 is number of students and 9 columns are different subjects and 10th column is their percentage  and I want to plot barplot for each column (1-9) with column (10) to see the distribution of the average in each subject. Like bar(1,10) but due to large value i.e.(600 entries) in row vector of both X and Y the barplot is not like bar plot with separate bars rather than its just colourful square screen with spikes in the middle. I couldn't find any function to have separate bars showing the distribution of data, any ideas?

Comment: With 600 students and 9 columns you have more bars than pixels on the screen. There is no function that could fix this.

Comment: @Daniel... But 600 bars is showing a square screen and I am not getting any idea about the data distribution but the same data when i give to another software it plots tiny 600 bars and each bar with different colors stacked on it... like they have used bar(x,y,'stacked').

I tried it the same with matlab and matlab shows same with no clue about data distribution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Matlab R2015b it works for me:

```
a = rand(600,1);
b = a/2;
bar([a b], 'stacked');
```

produces:

[image]

and when I zoom in:

[image]

Best,

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the question as solved if this is the case. Such that we know it's a closed question. Best,